# JWT: How to deal with it if the jwt contains too many roles and is therefore too large?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, keycloak

In my case, I have a Java Spring backend applications that requests its JWT via Keycloak.
Now I have the problem that my JWT contains a lot of roles, because this token is used to query a lot of applications.
But the token has now exceeded the maximum header size of 8KB due to all the roles.

Would you have any solutions on how to get the JWT smaller?
Changing the algorithm for hashing the signature makes no difference.

Comment: 8k is big, how many roles do you have? Maybe you'll have to remove most of the roles infos from the JWT and add special web services for sending detailled roles.

Comment: In this case, my token has roles of, say, 10 different clients. And each client has about 20 roles.

I need so many roles because this token is used to query the availability and functions of various applications.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to change Keycloak conf to define some of the roles at client level instead of having it all in "relam roles".

You'll also have to configure "client roles" mappers.

When an access-token is issued, it will contain only cross-clients roles (`realm_access.roles` claim) and roles for the specific client requesting user authentication (`resource_access.{clientId}.roles` claim).

Tutorials here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials